# Why does Chrome and Safari not see cookies for some sub-domains?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, safari

I have a site that's generating a cookie for example.com.  It is accessible in Firefox, Chrome 18 and Safari at both http://example.com and http://www.example.com.  However, I cannot access the cookie from http://test.me.example.com in webkit derived browsers. It works in Firefox.

I've tested this with domain= one of example.com and .example.com when setting the cookie from javascript.

The cookie has a path of / and has expires set.

Comment: Have a look at [Can subdomain.example.com set a cookie that can be read by example.com](http://serverfault.com/questions/153409/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com)

Comment: Yes, looking at that thread makes me think Firefox is correct and Chrome and Safari are not working properly.  Like I said, a first level sub domain works, but not two levels.  I would expect both www.example.com and something.wwww.example.com to both work if the cookie is defined as .example.com. I guess I was hoping someone knew either why this happens with Chrome or if there is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

How do you specify the subdomain?
Chrome expects cookies for subdomains to be prefixed with a dot
e.g. domain=.example.com

You may find this post useful: https://serverfault.com/questions/153409/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com

> Quoting from the same RFC2109 you read:
>
> ```
>    * A Set-Cookie from request-host x.foo.com for Domain=.foo.com would
>      be accepted.
> ```
>
> So subdomain.example.com can set a cookie for .example.com. So far so good.
>
> ```
>    The following rules apply to choosing applicable cookie-values from
>    among all the cookies the user agent has.
>
>    Domain Selection
>         The origin server's fully-qualified host name must domain-match
>         the Domain attribute of the cookie
> ```
>
> So do we have a domain-match?
>
> - A is a FQDN string and has the form NB, where N is a non-empty name
>      string, B has the form .B', and B' is a FQDN string.  (So, x.y.com
>      domain-matches .y.com but not y.com.)
>     But now example.com wouldn't domain-match .example.com according to the definition. But www.example.com (or any other "non-empty name" in the domain) > > would. This RFC is in theory obsoleted by RFC2965, which dictated things about forcing a leading dot for domains on Set-Cookie2 operations.
>
> More important, as noted by @Tony, is the real world. For a glimpse into what actual user agents are doing, see
>
> Firefox 3's nsCookieService.cpp
>   and
>
> Chrome's cookie_monster.cc
>   For perspective into what actual sites are doing, try playing with wget using > --save-cookies, --load-cookies, and --debug to see what's going on.
>
> You'll likely find that in fact most sites are using some combination of Set-> > Cookie from the older RFC spec with "Host" values, implicitly without a leading dot (as twitter.com does) or setting Domain values (with a leading dot) and redirecting to a server like www.example.com (as google.com does).

Comment: As noted in the original question, a leading dot was tried.